# Django form in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, backend

I was trying to build a **form** that make the **user** able to **upload** a picture from the website to **Media\Images** folder.

i try this but it dosent work

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class imgUpscalling(models.Model):
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import imgUpscalling

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = imgUpscalling
        fields = ('Image',)
```

**views.py**

```
def img_upscaler(request):
    context = {'from': ImageForm()}
    return render(request, "upsc_main.html",context)
```

**template.html**

```
<h1>Image Upscaler & Enhanced Resolution</h1>
    <h2>Select the Image</h2>
     <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

**can you notify me with the mistakes i did in the code? because the form is not shown in the template.
thanks a lot in advance**

Comment: There's a typo in your view. You called it `from`, not `form`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here:

1. Configure your settings.py correctly. When working with media, you need to configure your project to handle media files, as so:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

2. You also need to configure your urls.py on the project level, it will look something like the following:

```py
urlpatterns = [] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

3. Views.py

Your views should look something like this:

```py
def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # ensure you include request.files
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('upsc_main.html')  # Redirect to a success page
    else:
        form = ImageUploadForm()
    return render(request, 'yoururl.html', {'form': form})
```

Then obviously configure your apps urls.py, html templates etc.